# Google Grpc and powershell

Tags: powershell, grpc

I'm trying to build a simple Grpc client using Powershell. I cannot find any information on this. Does anybody have any pointers/examples for doing this.

I've tried loading the Grpc.Core.dll, however this just throws and

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Grpc.Core.dll")

GAC    Version        Location                                                                                                                         
---    -------        --------                                                                                                                         
False  v4.0.30319   C:\Users\vagrant\.nuget\packages\grpc.core\1.11.0\lib\netstandard1.5\Grpc.Core.dll
```

However, I can't access any of its methods.

So if I do this:

```
$grpctest =[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:Grpc.Core.dll")

$grpctest | Get-Member -Static
```

Comment: Have you tried `[Grpc.Core]::` and see if intellisense picks up?  Or `[grpc.core] | Get-Member -Static`

Comment: Yes - Neither seem to think its loaded.

Comment: Try `$myvar = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('C:\Grpc.Core.dll')` and see what members it has?

Comment: Since you're working with a .net library, I'd actually suggest using `$lib = Add-Type -Path 'C:\grpc.core.dll' -PassThru` and now you can work with the library using `$lib::MemberGoesHere`

Comment: Hmm when I try that it throws an exception.

Comment: Add-Type : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more informatio
n.
At line:1 char:8
+ $lib = Add-Type -Path "C:\Users\vagrant\.nuget\packages\grpc.core\1.1 ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], ReflectionTypeLoadException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

Comment: That's odd if Reflection is letting you load it.  OK, in your `$grpctest` variable, do `$grpctest.GetTypes()` and that should give you the library types you can access in powershell.

Comment: Thats the bit that's failing. I've pasted some output above

Comment: Are you trying to load a 32-bit DLL in 64-bit powershell?

Comment: Managed to fix this. There was a missing dependancy. System.Interactive.Asyn

Answer (score 4):

Managed to fix this. There was a missing dependancy. System.Interactive.Async

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Grpc\System.Interactive.Async.3.1.1\lib\net45\System.Interactive.Async.dll"
```

Now this works.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Grpc\System.Interactive.Async.3.1.1\lib\net45\System.Interactive.Async.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Grpc\Grpc.Core.1.11.0\lib\net45\Grpc.Core.dll"
$channel = New-Object Grpc.Core.Channel -ArgumentList @(,"127.0.0.1:50000", [Grpc.Core.ChannelCredentials]::Insecure)
$channel.ShutdownAsync().Wait()
```